# Problem in deducing an argument which is to be used in Proving Jacobi Triple Product Identity

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

While self studying analytic number theory from Tom M Apostol I could not think about how Apostol deduces this argument.

Image ( the part in which I have doubt is highlighted) -
[image]

[image]

> I am unable to think how Apostol changes index from m to n. I am having a problem in understanding it as index that has n only has $x^{2n} $  while on LHS $ x^m $ ( both of these are raised to power 2)  , so in RHS only even powers are summed.

Edit 1 -  I have another doubt in the same theorem. I am adding image ( with doubt highlighted)

[image]

> I have doubt that how does (1- $x^{4n}$) = (1-$x^{8n}$) (1-$x^{8n-4} $) ?

Can anybody please explain!!

Comment: If you have another question, you should ask it separately. Anyway, of course $1-x^{4n}\ne(1-x^{8n})(1-x^{8n-4})$. Nonetheless $\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1-x^{4n})=\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1-x^{8n})(1-x^{8n-4})$. It would be instructive for you to work out the first few factors on each side. Then it will be plain why the equality holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The powers of $i$ repeat between $i,-1,-i,1$. In particular the terms when $m$ is $1\mod 4$ cancel out the terms when $m$ is $-1\mod 4$ (the former give $i^m=i$ and the latter give $i^m=-i$). Leaving out those terms that cancel gives us
$$
\sum_{m\in\mathbb Z}x^{m^2}i^m=\sum_{m\in 2\mathbb Z}x^{m^2}i^m,
$$
where I write $2\mathbb Z$ for the even integers. Now let $m=2n$, so we find that
$$
\sum_{m\in 2\mathbb Z}x^{m^2}i^m=\sum_{n\in \mathbb Z}x^{(2n)^2}i^{2n}=\sum_{n\in \mathbb Z}x^{(2n)^2}(-1)^{n},
$$
since $i^2=-1$.

Comment: I understood your answer but I have another doubt in same proof which I have mentioned by editing the question. Can you please answer it.

Comment: It's better to ask it as a separate question... but anyway the answer to your edit is that there is more reindexing happening in the product. See the comment by L. S. above.

Comment: @user1551 why did you deleted your answer. That was a very nice explanation!!